# How to reference files that are in other folders in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am trying to know more about how paths work in python and I encountered the next problem.

When I try to call the full path I use the following -> "./Folder/archive2", and this works perfectly well when my .py file is in the same directory as the folder containing this 'archive2', but lets say the following:

```
    - Archive1 is in Folder1 (both archives are .py files)
    - Archive2 is in Folder2
    - Folder1 and Folder2 are in "RandomDirectory"
```

How can I get the path of Archive2 in Archive1 if they are in the same RandomDirectory but in different folders. Of course, copying the path is not an option because I want it to work on any computer so something like "./Folder/archive" would be great, so if I run the .py in other computer it would work as normal.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: To go back a directory use `../` in you case `../Folder2/Archive2`

Comment: To locate a specefic file in a **path** you can use `os` module  `os.listdir(path)` and search it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `..` to refer to the parent of the current directory.

If your working directory is `Archive1`, then:

- `..` refers to `Folder1`
- `../..` refers to `RandomDirectory`
- `../../Folder2` refers to `RandomDirectory/Folder2`
- and `../../Folder2/Archive2` refers to `RandomDirectory/Folder2/Archive2`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a structure like this:

```
Randomdirectory
├── Folder1
│   └── Archive1.py
└── Folder2
    └── Archive2.py
```

you can access `Archive2.py` from `Archive1.py` like this:

```
# code in Archive1.py
from pathlib import Path

print(Path('../Folder2/Archive2.py').exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use `os` library like this:

```
import os.path as pt

archive2_path = pt.join(pt.split(pt.dirname(pt.abspath(__file__)))[0], 'Folder2/Archive2.py')
```

In this case `archive2_path` is absolute path of Archive2.